# Meteor HTTP blank body with Content-Length 0 and response 302

Tags: http, meteor

A Meteor server code, using atmosphere HTTP package, is making a `POST` http call to a remote server, the `response.statusCode` comes back 302 and the response header contains:

> Content-Length: 0
>   Centent-Type: text/html
>   Location: otherURLThanVisitedIn_myURL?key=value

The response headers is the same also in firefox inspector panel when visiting the same page.

How is it that the page loads up and I can see the contents in the browser but when I `console.log(response.content.length)` I get 0, i.e. no string content received? Thanks

```
let myURL = getURL();
let myHeaders = getHeadersObj();
let myParams = getParamsObj();
const response = HTTP.call('POST', myURL, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: myHeaders,
  params: myParams
});
```

Comment: Your browser knows how to handle HTTP 302 and your server code does not? Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 302 status code means there's a redirection. Apparently the Meteor package doesn't follow the redirection automatically.

The first thing to check is that you have a recent version of the package. There was [an issue about redirects for POST request](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2808).

If it's ok, you can use the `followRedirect` parameter in the options:

```
const response = HTTP.call('POST', myURL, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: myHeaders,
  params: myParams,
  followRedirect: true
});
```

Comment: The package version 1.1.5 "latest", the extra `followRedirect` was added as suggested for no avail. I still get empty `response.content` back as originally posted.

Comment: it is not `followRedirect` but `followRedirects` found after so much pain. Thx

Comment: Oh sorry the type caused trouble. Edited to save others some time.